# How to set null value in Wrangler

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm ingesting csv file from Google Cloud Storage (db dump from MySql) and there is a field I would like to save as Integer (initially, all fields are String). The problem is that in a file all NULL values are filled with "\N" value and I cannot change column type:

[This is how it is loaded from csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T1hh.png)

I tried to use find-and-replace function, but it does not change these \N values.
When I try to change column type, this is the error message I receive:

[Error when trying to convert to Integer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx1de.png)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom transform to convert all \N values to null and then you can change the data type to integer.

You can create a custom transform by clicking the column dropdown and then going to Custom Transform: [image: screenshot of UI]

Then you can use the following transform to replace all \N values with null (replace `col1` with the name of your column):

`col1=="\N"?null:col1`

Then you can change the data type to integer and it should work.